# PowerShell New-PSDrive not working with authentication

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to map a SharePoint document library as the letter Z. Mapping the drive in Windows Explorer as 'Map network drive' and giving in the credentials works fine.

But how can I map this drive within PowerShell and without using the Windows Explorer GUI step in between for the authentication?

I tried using the `-Credential` switch of `New-PSDrive` but then PowerShell complains that the drive isn't found...

**Code:**

```
$Sharepoint = 'http://My site/Documents/Folders - Permission matrix'
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Sharepoint -Credential $Credential
```

**Error:**

```
New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "http://My site/Documents/Folders - Permission matrix" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your syntax is invalid for `New-PSDrive`. FileSystem Provider doesn't contain elements that are specified with `http` prefix.

You should use `\\My site\Documents\Folders - Permission matrix` as an input to `New-PSDrive` because FileSystem provider accepts UNC paths.

Comment: Thank you majkinetor, this was indeed the problem.